# Discordjs hierarchy permissions

Tags: discord

I have a ban command but for some reason a moderator can ban an admin. How do I set up hierarchy?

ex. A mod can ban A Admin when the admin role is above mod.

Thank u!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a bit late but here is a working solution for your problem.

```
if (message.member.roles.cache.find(role => role.position > message.mentions.members.first().roles.highest.position)) {
    // If role is above 
    // Here you can enter the code for banning the mentioned user
  } else {
    // If role isn't above
  }
```

You have to check if the user who enters the command has a higer role than the user who should get banned by the bot.